# List View Builder gives an error renderingBox

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class _BooksPageState extends State<BooksPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            const Text(
              "Hello",
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),
            ),
            const Text(
              "Name Surname",
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 25),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            const Text(
              "My books",
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                shrinkWrap: true,
              
                itemCount: 3,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Container(
                   padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        color: Colors.white,
                        image: DecorationImage(
                            image: AssetImage("assets/images/pride.jpg"), 
                            )),
                  );
                })
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> The error message which I got is :Exception caught by rendering
> library ═════════════════════════════════ RenderBox was not laid out:
> RenderRepaintBoundary#25e0c relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT
> NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> 'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
> package:flutter/…/rendering/box.dart:1 Failed assertion: line 1982 pos
> 12: 'hasSize'
>
> I have tried to add expanded and sized box but it does not work

Comment: You can check [this](https://youtu.be/jckqXR5CrPI)

Answer (score 2):

My solution is use Expanded widget to expand remain space.
Wrap ListView.builder with Expanded widget .

```
 Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: 20,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      color: Colors.white,
                      image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage("assets/images/pride.jpg"),
                      )),
                );
              }),
        )
```

Comment: I have tried, It does not work